# Qt signal connect failing

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I have a QListWidget that is in a QGridLayout within a QWizardPage. The items in the QListWidget are all of the xml files in a directory. I have everything working but for the signals. I missing something critical but simple I'm sure.

I've looked at the [QListWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) documentation and at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311241/qlistwidget-event-on-item-click) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008611/detecting-if-an-item-is-clicked-at-at-some-row-in-a-qlistwidget) post, among others. Everything seems to say itemClicked( QListWidgetItem* ) should be what I need but it and others aren't working i.e. my function new_sequence_selected is never getting called. Connect is also never returning a handle for this, always false.

Most of the signals I've tried are in the code below.

Also my browseButton is working just fine.

Additional info: Working in Win7, VS2012, Qt5, Qt VS Add-in 1.2.2

Thanks in advance for the help!!

creator.h

```
#include <qwizard.h>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QHeaderView>

class Sequence_selectPage :  public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public: Sequence_selectPage( QWidget *parent = 0 );

private slots:
    void browse();
private:
    QListWidget *sequenceList;
    QDir sequences_dir_path;
    QString selected_sequence;
};
```

creator.cpp

```
#include "creator.h"

Sequence_selectPage::Sequence_selectPage( QWidget *parent ) : QWizardPage( parent )
{
    first_round = true;

    setTitle( tr( "Select an xml" ) );
    // setup path to Sequence
    sequences_dir_path.absolutePath();
    sequences_dir_path.cd( "Sequence" );


    //set up the list for the files
    sequenceList = new QListWidget( this );
    //sequenceList->setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection );
    QStringList filter;
    filter << "*.xml";

    //add xmls to list
    foreach( QString File, sequences_dir_path.entryList( filter, QDir::Files ) )      //(QStringList)"*.xml"
    {
        sequenceList->addItem( File );
    }

    if( sequenceList->count() > 0 )
    {
        sequenceList->item( 0 )->setSelected( true );
    }

    browseButton = buttonBuilder( tr( "Browse..." ), this, SLOT( browse() ) );

    /*********** Figure out this signal **********/
    connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( sequenceList->itemClicked( QListWidgetItem* i ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* i) ) );
    //connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( itemClicked( QListWidgetItem* ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* ) ) );
    //connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( itemActivated( QListWidgetItem* ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* ) ) );
    //connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( itemEntered( QListWidgetItem* ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* ) ) );
    //connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( itemPressed( QListWidgetItem* ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* ) ) );
    //connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( itemSelectionChanged( ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( ) ) );
    //connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( itemDoubleClicked( QListWidgetItem* ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* ) ) );
    //connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( itemChanged( QListWidgetItem* ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* ) ) );
    //connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( currentItemChanged( QListWidgetItem*, QListWidgetItem* ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* ) ) );

    selectpageLayout = new QGridLayout( this );
    selectpageLayout->addWidget( sequenceList, 0, 0, 1, 2 );
    selectpageLayout->addWidget( browseButton, 1, 1 );

    setLayout( selectpageLayout );
}

void Sequence_selectPage::new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* sequence )
{
    selected_sequence = sequence->text();
}
```

buttonBuilder code

```
QPushButton *buttonBuilder( QString &button_name, QObject *receiver, const char *member )
{
    QPushButton *mybutton = new QPushButton( button_name );
    QObject::connect( mybutton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), receiver, member );
    return mybutton;
}
```

Comment: Does the connect function return true? Btw, the `sequences_dir_path.absolutePath();` statement is needless.

Comment: @LaszloPapp No none of the attempts at connect return a handle, all return 0.

Comment: Did you use the Q_OBJECT macro inside the class declaration?

Comment: @PrisonMonkeys Yes I did, edited post to show all #includes and class definition.

Comment: Try: connect( sequenceList, SIGNAL( itemClicked( QListWidgetItem* ) ), this, SLOT( new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* ) ) );

Comment: @ManuelH Thanks for the suggestion but unless I'm missing something that's the same as the first commented out connect I tried. But I tried it anyway and it doesn't return a handle either.

Comment: Try @ManuelH's suggestion together with the answer of otisonoza below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare `new_sequence_selected` as slot.

Try this:

```
#include <qwizard.h>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QHeaderView>

class Sequence_selectPage :  public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public: Sequence_selectPage( QWidget *parent = 0 );

private slots:
    void browse();
    void new_sequence_selected( QListWidgetItem* sequence ); //<-- ADDED THIS
private:
    QListWidget *sequenceList;
    QDir sequences_dir_path;
    QString selected_sequence;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it would be something like that.