# Making my listed items in QListview emit signals when clicked

Tags: qt, qtableview, qlistview

I want to make each item listed in `QTableview`, when clicked, emit a signal that opens up a dialog for instance. I need help on this

```
 QFileSystemModel *listModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    QString directory = "/home/uboho/monitor_test_module/logs/tmp/etc/nodes";
    ui->clusterList->setModel(listModel);
    ui->clusterList->setRootIndex(listModel->setRootPath(directory));
    ui->clusterList->
          setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed |
                         QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);

}

    bool displayTable::DoubleClicked (const QModelIndex index )
    {
        QDialog * test = new QDialog();
        test->show();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting if an item is clicked at at some row in a QlistWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008611/detecting-if-an-item-is-clicked-at-at-some-row-in-a-qlistwidget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QTableView` inherits [`QAbstractItemView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) that emits the signal [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked). You can register a slot/callback that creates a popup with the QTableView object for the clicked signal.

```
// Qt 5
connect(theQTableView, &QAbstractItemView::clicked,
        theCallbackReceiver, &CallbackReceiver::clickedCallback);

// Qt 4
connect(theQTableView, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),
        theCallbackReceiver, SLOT(clickedCallback(QModelIndex)));
```

Via the `index` parameter of the `clicked` signal you can find out which item was clicked.

Comment: It should also be same as OP code: `connect(ui->clusterList, &QAbstractItemView::clicked, this, &displayTable::DoubleClicked);`

Comment: Exactly @Mohammad